# How do I take photos of data center and control room

Tags: controls, photo

I'm starting an engineering firm, I also happen to be a professional photographer. I'm in the process of coding my webpage now and... guess what... I need pictures of control rooms, data centers and power plant industrial stuffs. How on earth can I go about this. Stock photos are overpriced and, well, they've likely been used many times already. So I'd to take my own... but how do I get these companies to let me shoot their assets?